# Windows 10 dark theme that looks like dark Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows-10, colors, themes, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 has beautiful dark theme out of the box, which is very easy on eyes (especially in night). There are little details like different shades of blacks/browns on various UI elements that make sense together. Yet is is minimalistic without excessive effects.

Is there some way to have this dark theme, or something as close as possible, for entire Windows 10? I was googling for dark windows themes but could find anything of this quality...

VS2015 screenshot: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3xOk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, today (2016-08-02) Microsoft announced Windows 10 "Anniversary Update" which features dark theme for whole OS. So that is pretty much what I was looking for.

http://www.anandtech.com/show/10537/windows-10-anniversary-update-the-road-to-redstone/3

Comment: its not like visual studio though

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not a big fan of the Dark theme for Visual Studio, the only thing I can think of that is close to what you want to achieve is High Contrast Mode.  Simply search "High Contrast Settings" in the search feature on Windows 10, and pick your poison.

Google Chrome also has some nice extensions for Dark themes.  It can even detect when you computer is in High Contrast Mode, and recommend a dark theme for you to use.

Comment: It is exactly what I want to avoid. The visual studio 2015 dark theme is nice for the eyes, the windows high contrast theme is just hurting my eyes and it looks terrible.

Comment: How about trying [this](https://devbest.com/threads/enable-global-dark-theme-in-windows-10.70958/).  Sorry for misunderstanding you the first time.  If this is more up your alley, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Wow that looks promissing! Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't seem to like dark themes. It seems you are aware of third-party theming and [Deviantart](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/customization/skins/windows/win10/) has a category related to Windows 10 visual styles, some of which are very beautiful